# How to add data-animation="fadeinup" inside <div> using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add data-animation='fadeinup' dynamically inside the `<div>`, for eg: <`div>` to `<div data-animation='fadeinup'>` using Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), like this

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
element.setAttribute('data-animation', 'fadeinup');
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

also you can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
element.dataset.animation = 'fadeinup';
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, it was working like a charm. Thanks. But if i try for Class name its not working. Could you please give me the code for Class name